# show a ViewController from a Detail View Controller in a UISplitViewController

Tags: swift, fullscreen, viewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

**My aim is:** To show a `popUpViewController` in my project in which the user can add a "lesson" (adding a `tableViewCell` to a `tableView`) and then save it. 
So when the user presses a button inside the `DetailViewController` of a `UISplitViewController` , the `popUpViewController` should show.
I also want the pop-up to be shown as fullscreen with just a small window in the middle and the rest should be black with 0.5 alpha, transparent.

**My problem is**: I can't find out how I have to show the popUp.

**What I've tried and my results:**

**Tried**: Showing it with `present(Viewcontroller, animated:, completion: )`

**Result**: It shows fullscreen but the other VC isnt visible in the background anymore.

**Tried**: The following snippet:

```
let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popUpVC") as! PopUpViewController

self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

**Result**: The view isnt fullscreen but only the size of the detail View Controller (doesnt cover the part of the masterViewController on the left.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try again with `present(Viewcontroller, animated:, completion: )`
and using `modalPresentationStyle` with `formSheet` eg:

```
let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popUpVC") as! PopUpViewController
popOverVC.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
self.present(popOverVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: didnt quite work with formSheet, but it did work with .custom, so thank you very much for giving me the right idea and have a nice day :)